# Create array of objects by iterating through an observable

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an Angular component, that subscribes to an observable, returned by an Angular Service.

**Component:** 
**help.component.ts**

```
import { WikiService } from '../../../services/wiki.service';

import { WikiTree } from '../../../interfaces/WikiTree';

export class HelpComponent implements OnInit {

    wikiTree$: Observable<WikiTree>

    public infoCards: Array<Object>;

    constructor(private wikiService: WikiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this.wikiTree$ = this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy();
            this.wikiTree$.subscribe(()=>{
               //TODO: Create infoCards array by iterating through the results array inside the wikiTree observable.
            }
        }
}
```

The `wikiTree$` Observable has the following JSON, converted to TypeScript:

```
{
    "page": {
        "results": [
            {
                "id": "123456789",
                "type": "page",
                "status": "current",
                "title": "Start here",
                "extensions": {
                    "position": 0
                },
                "_links": {
                    "webui": "/display/MYSPACE/Start+here",
                    "edit": "/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=123456789",
                    "tinyui": "/x/BQD2Mw",
                    "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/123456789"
                },
                "_expandable": {
                    "container": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE",
                    "metadata": "",
                    "operations": "",
                    "children": "/rest/api/content/123456789/child",
                    "restrictions": "/rest/api/content/123456789/restriction/byOperation",
                    "history": "/rest/api/content/123456789/history",
                    "ancestors": "",
                    "body": "",
                    "version": "",
                    "descendants": "/rest/api/content/123456789/descendant",
                    "space": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "567890123",
                "type": "page",
                "status": "current",
                "title": "FAQ",
                "extensions": {
                    "position": 1
                },
                "_links": {
                    "webui": "/display/MYSPACE/FAQ",
                    "edit": "/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=567890123",
                    "tinyui": "/x/HQD2Mw",
                    "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/567890123"
                },
                "_expandable": {
                    "container": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE",
                    "metadata": "",
                    "operations": "",
                    "children": "/rest/api/content/567890123/child",
                    "restrictions": "/rest/api/content/567890123/restriction/byOperation",
                    "history": "/rest/api/content/567890123/history",
                    "ancestors": "",
                    "body": "",
                    "version": "",
                    "descendants": "/rest/api/content/567890123/descendant",
                    "space": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE"
                }
            }
        ],
        "start": 0,
        "limit": 25,
        "size": 2,
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/998877665/child/page"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "base": "https://wiki.abc.com",
        "context": "",
        "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/998877665/child"
    },
    "_expandable": {
        "attachment": "/rest/api/content/998877665/child/attachment",
        "comment": "/rest/api/content/998877665/child/comment"
    }
}
```

**TypeScript: WikiTree.ts**

```
export interface WikiTree {
    page: Page;
    _links: Links;
    _expandable: Expandable;
  }
  export interface Page {
    results?: (ResultsEntity)[] | null;
    start: number;
    limit: number;
    size: number;
    _links: Links1;
  }
  export interface ResultsEntity {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    status: string;
    title: string;
    extensions: Extensions;
    _links: Links2;
    _expandable: Expandable1;
  }
  export interface Extensions {
    position: number;
  }
  export interface Links2 {
    webui: string;
    edit: string;
    tinyui: string;
    self: string;
  }
  export interface Expandable1 {
    container: string;
    metadata: string;
    operations: string;
    children: string;
    restrictions: string;
    history: string;
    ancestors: string;
    body: string;
    version: string;
    descendants: string;
    space: string;
  }
  export interface Links1 {
    self: string;
  }
  export interface Links {
    base: string;
    context: string;
    self: string;
  }
  export interface Expandable {
    attachment: string;
    comment: string;
  }
```

I would like to iterate through "page" -> "results" array in the `wikiTree$` observable in the subscribe method and create an array of objects called `infoCards`, as defined in the component with this JSON, with some of the values coming from `wikiTree$` observable. :

```
[{
        "title": "Start here",
        "titleLink": "/page/wiki/123456789",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "FAQ",
        "titleLink": "/page/wiki/567890123",
        "children": []
    }
    ]
```

How do I do that?

Update:

**InfoCard Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-card',
  templateUrl: './info-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-card.component.css']
})
export class InfoCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('infoCard') infoCard: Array<Object>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following subscription will create new objects based on the structure you had provided whenever new data comes in. I am assuming you only need title and titleLink in the specified format and `children` array is derived from another service ?

```
this.wikiTree$.subscribe( res => {
    const newInfoCards = res.page.results.map(result => ({
        "title": result.title,
        "titleLink": "/page/wiki/"+ result._links.self.split('/').pop(),
        "children": []
    }),
    this.infoCards.concat(newInfoCards);
})
```

Comment: yes.. Children array will be a result of an observable from a different function in the WikiService array. Basically, it's a different API call to get the data.

Comment: I get an error: Block-scoped variable 'newInfoCards' used before its declaration.

Comment: are you sure you used the same code ? the order may be important since we used const. You can remove the error if you use `var` instead.
I am assuming you used `concat` before the map statement ?

Comment: I think that concat doesn't work, because infoCards is defined as an array of objects. We may need some thing else there.

Comment: Since it is an array, concat should work fine regardless of the values inside, in any case, you could also try `this.infoCards = [...this.infoCards,...newInfoCards]`

Comment: One way it causes error is if this.infoCards is initially undefined or empty string. You should initialise it to ` [] ` empty array for it to work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187831/discussion-between-jake-and-dhananjai-pai).

Answer (score 1):

If I would face this then I would solve this like below:

At first, I would create a **Model** (Class) like the models in your **WikiTree.ts** for InfoCard. I am making this a `Class` to create an Object of it inside the subscribe method-

```
export class InfoCard{
        title: string;
        titleLink: string;
        children: string;
  }
```

After that in the **Component: help.component.ts** I would declare infoCards like this-

```
infoCards: InfoCard[]=[];
```

Obviously, you have to import **InfoCard** from **WikiTree.ts**-

```
import { InfoCard} from '../../../interfaces/WikiTree';
```

Then inside the subscribe method, I would map the data coming as Observable-

```
    this.wikiTree$.subscribe(data =>{
      data.page.results.map(
       result=>{
          let newInfoCard = new InfoCard();
          newInfoCard.title = result.title;
          newInfoCard.children= result._expandable.children;
          newInfoCard.titleLink= result._links.self;
          this.infoCards = [this.infoCards, ...newInfoCard]
        }
       )
     }
```

As you've added the Component Part, so you can try this also-

Initialize the array-

```
infoCards: Array<Object>= new Array();
```

There may be more options to get it done. I am sharing mine. Let me know if you don't understand anything or have a question or the mistakes I have made.

```
    forkJoin(
        this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy(),
        this.wikiService.GetWikiChildren()
    ).subscribe(([data, children]) => {
        data.page.results.map(
            result => {
                this.infoCards.push({
                    'title': result.title,
                    'titleLink': result._links.self,
                    'children': children.whatEver
                });
            }
        )
    });
```

And, if the children call depends on previous service call you can try something like this-

```
  this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy().subscribe(
    data=>{
      data.page.results.map(
        result=>{
          this.wikiService.GetWikiChildren(result.id).subscribe(
            child=>{
                this.infoCards.push({
                  'title': result.title,
                  'titleLink': result._links.self,
                  'children': child.whatEver
                    });
            }
          )
        }
      )
    }
  )
```

Comment: In my code, I have a component called InfoCard, that generates some HTML based on the infoCard array. So, not sure about the model approach. I might just need a simple way to create an infoCards array in the subscribe method. Also, the children array needs to draw data from another observable not mentioned here. So, that is probably a call to a different function in the WikiService.

Comment: I have to see the implementation of the component of InfoCard then. And as you will call another service to get the children, you can use mergeMap or forkJoin.

Comment: added the InfoCard component to the question for your reference.

Comment: Added other options.